# Add a dhcp and a static network in Ubuntu VM

Tags: 14.04, networking, vmware

I am using VMWare work station. `eth0` is set as NAT and `eth1` is host-only.

I want to connect to a static network and internet but so far can only connect to static part.

Here is my network interfaces on */etc/network/interfaces*:

```
eth0 auto
iface eth0 inet dhcp
eth1 auto
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.0.102
....
....
```

My `ip route` shows default is going through 192.168.0.1 and ping to all VMs to that network works, but while pinging real networks like google.com it says hosts are unreachable.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be caused because of the **default route** of your Ubuntu. Your default route is currently your LAN (host-only) gateway which doesn't have any access to the internet. Your default route must point to your NAT network:

```
sudo route add default dev eth0
```

Comment: can it be made permanent in interfaces file?

Comment: Yes, I've never tried this but apparently, you can use the post-up option in **/etc/network/interfaces** in order to force a specific default route. and make sure that another one doesn't become one.

`auto eth0`
`iface eth1 inet dhcp`
`post-up route add default via [gateway-ip-address] dev eth0`

`auto eth1`
`iface eth1 inet static`
`[...]`
`post-up route del default dev eth1`
Source: http://xmodulo.com/how-to-set-default-route-in-linux.html

However, for this conf, you need to know your NAT gateway's IP (use **Virtual Network Editor** of VMWare).

Keep me informed if it works